# Multisite Wordpress subsite redirect to main site

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I had a problem which I created a Multisite Wordpress.
I used Nginx for my web server.
Multisite was enabled on Wordpress which a main site is [freelayers.net](http://freelayers.net)
When I created a new website everything is work well. I can recive a successful email. But when I try to access the subsites like [cantho.freelayers.net](http://cantho.freelayers.net). It always redirect me to [freelayers.net](http://freelayers.net)
I had also add a wildcard record (*) on DNS manager. It looks like:

> - (IP address /URL) my server IP       (Record Type) A/Address

I thinks something wrong in my conf file on Nginx but I can find any solution
This is configuration file for the main site.

```
server {
    listen  9880;
    server_name  www.freelayers.net;
    rewrite ^/(.*) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1;
    root   /home/web/freelayers;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    #if (!-e $request_filename) {
    #    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    #}
    access_log /home/web/freelayers/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/web/freelayers/logs/error.log;
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
        }
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Please give some ideas about this issue! Thanks for any reply!

Comment: can you explain the concept of multi-site, are these different installation, or is this a single installation that should server different sites ?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! This is a single Wordpress installation on a server. I try to set up a multisite for this website

Comment: and how is wordpress supposed to know which website you are using? from the domain name ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you explain more? This is first time I works with Multisite so there are some thing I can not caught